# asymptotic expression for the integral $\Re\int_0^1 dx \sqrt{\frac{(1-x)x}{x+2ax-a}}$ in the limit $a\ll1$

Tags: calculus, integration, asymptotics

I would like to evaluate the integral
$$
\Re\int_0^1 dx \sqrt{\frac{(1-x)x}{x+2ax-a}}
$$
in the case of $0<a\ll1$. The $0$th order term becomes $2/3$ and I would like to know the $1$st order term with respect to $a$. (I think this term includes logarithm, e.g. $a\log a$.)

This integral is derived approximately from
$$
\int_0^{y_2} dy \sqrt{\frac{(y-y_1)(y_2-y)}{y}} ,
$$
where $y_1=-\eta a, y_2=\eta(1+a)\ (\eta>0)$. Can anyone get the approximate form of the integral with respect to $a\ll1$?

---

Thank you for the reply. I checked the validity with numerical calculation and it seems to correct.　I plotted
\begin{align}
    \int_0^{y_2}dy \sqrt{\frac{(y-y_1)(y_2-y)}{y}}dy
    &=\eta^{3/2}(1+2a)^2\Re \int_{0}^1dx\sqrt{\frac{x(1-x)}{-(1-x)a+x(1+a)}}
\end{align}
and $F(a)$ is the expression with complete elliptic integrals.

[image]

Comment: Isn’t the zeroeth order term positive $2/3$, as that is the value at $a=0$?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It's typo.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y_2-y$?

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Comment: In that case I got $$
\int_0^{y_2 } {\sqrt {\frac{{(y - y_1 )(y_2  - y)}}{y}} dy}  = \frac{2}{3}\eta ^{3/2} \sqrt {1 + 2a} \left( {E\!\left( {\sqrt {\frac{{1 + a}}{{1 + 2a}}} } \right) + aK\!\left( {\sqrt {\frac{{1 + a}}{{1 + 2a}}} } \right)} \right)
$$ in terms of the [complete elliptic integrals](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.2.E8). Then one may use the [known asymptotics](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.12).

Comment: Could you please tell me what variable transformation would yield that equation?

Answer (score 5):

Let us denote the value of the integral by $I(a)$. We telescope the integral as
$$I(a) = \Re\int_0^1 \! \left(\sqrt{\frac{(1-x)x}{x+2ax-a}} - \sqrt{\frac{x}{x-a}} \right)\,dx +\Re\int_0^1 \!  \sqrt{\frac{x}{x-a}}\,dx = I_0(a) +I_1(a)$$
which is valid as the integral (with $0<a<1$)
$$I_1(a) = \Re \int_0^1\!  \sqrt{\frac{x}{x-a}}\,dx = \sqrt{1-a} + a \mathop{\rm artanh}\Bigl(\sqrt{1-a}\Bigr)$$
has a finite value.

We note that for $a \ll 1$, the integral has the asymptotic expansion
$$ I_1(a) \sim 1 - \frac{a}{2} (\log(a/4) +1) \,. $$

For the remaining integral $I_0$, we expand in $a$ in the integrand and obtain
$$I_0(a) = \int_0^1\! \Bigl(\sqrt{1-x} -1 + \frac{(1-2x) \sqrt{1-x} -1}{2x} a + O(a^2)\Bigr) \,dx\,.$$
The integrals can be evaluated separately with the result
$$I_0(a) = -\frac13 + (\log 2 - \tfrac 53) a + O(a^2)\,.$$

Putting everything together, we obtain
$$I(a) \sim \frac23 + (\log 2 -\tfrac{13}{6}) a -\frac{a}{2} \ln(a/4)\,. $$

Comment: Of course some of the subresults are nontrivial. I hope that you can follow the general argument (extract the singularity in a simpler integral $I_1$ which can be solved exactly). Please feel free to ask further questions about the integral which have to be solved (even though some of them might be a question by themselves). If you spot mistakes, please tell me such that I can correct the answer.

Comment: The method of excluding integrals involving singularities seems to be applicable to a variety of problems. Thank you very much.
I posted the results of the numerical calculations at my question as a reply.

Comment: Could you please explain why you extract that term? @Fabian

Comment: @MathFail: first, one has to understand where the problem of the integrand is. A naive Taylor expansion of the integrand yields $\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{1-x} a/2x$. While the integral of the first term converges (it is $2/3$), the second term diverges. The problem is the behavior close to $x=0$. The Taylor expansion (in $a$) does a very bad job to approximate the integrand close to $x=0$ (try to plot the two functions and you see what I mean). So the idea then is to find a "simple" function that captures the behavior for $x$ small.

Comment: We approximate $1-x \approx 1$ in the numerator and $2a x \approx 0$ in the denominator (the $2a x$ is quadratically small, as both $x$ and $a$ are small). (try to plot my approximation to see that it does a much better job than the Taylor expansion).

Comment: Got it, this method is great! Is there a general principle about how to select the approximate function at the singularity? @Fabian

Comment: @MathFail: I don't know of any general principle except "choose the function as simple as possible while still capturing the essence of the singularity" (which here is the sqrt-singularity for $x \approx a \ll 1$)

Comment: Got it, thank you very much! @Fabian

Answer (score 2):

For $y_1=-\eta a$, $y_2=\eta(1+a)$ with $\eta>0$, as @Gary wrote in comments, the result is (using Mathematica notation)
$$\Re\Bigg[\int_0^{y_2}  \sqrt{\frac{(y-y_1)(y_2-y)}{y}}\,dy\Bigg] =\frac{2 \,\eta ^{3/2}}{3 }\,  \sqrt{1+2 a} \left(a K\left(\frac{a+1}{2 a+1}\right)+E\left(\frac{a+1}{2
   a+1}\right)\right)$$

where appear complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kinds.

Expanded  around $a=0$,
$$f(a)= \sqrt{1+2 a} \left(a K\left(\frac{a+1}{2 a+1}\right)+E\left(\frac{a+1}{2
   a+1}\right)\right)$$  gives
$$f(a)=1-\frac{3}{4} (\log (a)-4 \log (2)-1)a-\frac{3}{64} (10 \log (a)-17-40 \log (2))a^2+$$
$$\frac{3}{256} (13 \log (a)+10-52 \log (2))a^3-\frac{3}{16384}(564 \log (a)+943-2256 \log (2))a^4+$$
$$\frac{3}{131072} (3990 \log (a)+8753-15960 \log (2))a^5-$$
$$\frac{3}{2621440} (82355 \log (a)+208337-329420 \log (2))a^6+$$
$$\frac{1}{8388608}(907830 \log (a)+2500343-3631320 \log (2))a^7+\cdots$$
which seems to be quite good. The table below reports the approximate and exact values of $\sqrt{1+2 a}\,f(a)$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} &\text{exact} \\
 0.00 & 1.00000 & 1.00000 \\
 0.05 & 1.26247 & 1.26247 \\
 0.10 & 1.48677 & 1.48677 \\
 0.15 & 1.70316 & 1.70316 \\
 0.20 & 1.91733 & 1.91733 \\
 0.25 & 2.13173 & 2.13173 \\
 0.30 & 2.34762 & 2.34762 \\
 0.35 & 2.56575 & 2.56577 \\
 0.40 & 2.78658 & 2.78663 \\
 0.45 & 3.01040 & 3.01050 \\
 0.50 & 3.23739 & 3.23758 \\
 0.55 & 3.46766 & 3.46800 \\
 0.60 & 3.70130 & 3.70184 \\
 0.65 & 3.93834 & 3.93916 \\
 0.70 & 4.17884 & 4.17999 \\
 0.75 & 4.42287 & 4.42433 \\
 0.80 & 4.67052 & 4.67220 \\
 0.85 & 4.92196 & 4.92359 \\
 0.90 & 5.17746 & 5.17848 \\
 0.95 & 5.43743 & 5.43685 \\
 1.00 & 5.70246 & 5.69870
\end{array}
\right)$$

You must take care that the high order terms play a significant role when $a$ start to be close to $1$.

Looking at the absolute values of the coefficients $c_n$ of the expansion

$$f(a)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\,a^n $$ for $a=1$, they decrease from $n=0$ to $n=7$; but for $n>7$ they increase a bit more than exponentially (they alternate in sign).

A quick and dirty nonlinear regression $(10 \leq n \leq 100)$
$$\log(|c_n|)= -\alpha + \beta\,n^\gamma$$ gives  $(R^2=0.999992)$

$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha  & 7.51907 & 0.05261 & \{7.41450,7.62363\} \\
 \beta   & 0.36650 & 0.00393 & \{0.35870,0.37430\} \\
 \gamma  & 1.11063 & 0.00221 & \{1.10625,1.11501\} \\
\end{array}$$

For a better approximation for large values of $a$, the expansion around $a=1$ is quite simple
$$\frac 1{\sqrt{3}} f(a)=\left(K\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)+\frac{3}{2} K\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)(a-1)+$$
$$\frac{1}{16}\left(5 K\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-3 E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)(a-1)^2+\frac{1}{96}\left(5 E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-4 K\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)(a-1)^3+$$
$$\frac{1}{4608}\left(59 K\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-121 E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)(a-1)^4+$$
$$\frac{1}{138240}\left(2264 E\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)-769 K\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)(a-1)^5+\cdots$$ For $a=0.75$, this would give $4.42434$.

For this expansion, the coefficients (alternating in sign) are very nice; they decrease exponentially

Comment: Whilst scrolling down, starting to see the many numbers and the table, I immediately thought "this is Claude Leibovici", and indeed here you are :D I so love those answers of yours.